# JavaScript - Parsing only part of the URL but not everything after designated location

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, parsing, url

I have a script (JS) that parses the URL suffixes and then from that data defines variables.

THE URL: **http://www.example.com/somepage.html?bg=white&&accent=gray**

```
var PAGE = {
    bg: location.href.match(/bg=(.*)/)[1],
    accent: location.href.match(/accent=(.*)/)[1]
};

alert("Page Background: " + PAGE.bg + " \n Page Complements: " + PAGE.accent);
```

Note, the url gets its params from a page I created that goes before visiting that page (the user clicks a variety of options, then hits a "Next" button).
    
    Everything works pretty well, except the `PAGE.bg` returns `white&&accent=gray`, obviously returning everything *after* `bg=`. I want to know how to *only* return the BG, so like do a parseFloat of `PAGE.bg` or something like that, but being a beginner at JavaScript, I don't know how to do it, and it's kind of a detailed problem so I didn't have any luck googling it. Any ideas? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
bg: location.href.match(/bg=([^&]*)/)[1],
```

Comment: The issue is that you used greedy regular expressions that matched your '&&' characters as well. `[^&]` means "all characters except `&`."

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an existing library? [URL.js](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/) is really fantastic, and does exactly what you want. It can create hashes from the URI's query parameters.

See [this page](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/docs.html#accessors-search) for the exact documentation of working with search/query strings.

```
var uri = new URI('http://www.example.com/somepage.html?bg=white&&accent=gray')
var PAGE = uri.search(true)
```

This way, if you add more query parameters later, you'll still get them in the object represetation

Comment: Yeah, I stumbled across this earlier while trying to research my problem, and it looks great and all, and I might look into it, but for now, with the current project, it just doesn't suit me.